# Type Definition not getting fetched | Visual Studio Code

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I recently started using Visual Studio Code. I was working on an angular project when i noticed VS Code simply won't download the definition for angular.

I can't even find the directory where the definitions are stored.

[image: VS Code]

I click on `Download type definition angular.d.ts` but nothing happens. I keep getting squiggly under `angular`.

My VS Code version is 0.10.3.
I've tried manually putting the definition statement but it wont help either.

```
/// /// https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts
```

from this source [John Papa Quick Fix](http://www.johnpapa.net/intellisense-witha-visual-studio-code/)

Comment: the format for adding the reference manually is `///<reference path="path to typings"/>`.  there is no way that that `/// /// pathToWebsite` would work.

Comment: I've tried that as well. It doesn't work